# How to find if the heights of a triangle with given sides can make up another triangle

Tags: c++

I'm solving a problem I found on the Internet. You input 3 integers - the sides of a triangle. The goal is to tell if you can make a triangle out of the 3 heights of the triangle

I tried writing this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    float a, b, c, p, h1, h2, h3;
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    p = 0.5 * (a + b + c);
    h1 = (2 * sqrt(p * (p - a) * (p - b) * (p - c))) / a;
    h2 = (2 * sqrt(p * (p - a) * (p - b) * (p - c))) / b;
    h3 = (2 * sqrt(p * (p - a) * (p - b) * (p - c))) / c;
    if (h1 * h2 > h3 && h1 * h3 > h2 && h3 * h2 > h1) {
        cout << "YES";
    }
    else {
        cout << "NO";
    }
}
```

But I keep getting only 70/100 points for this one. Some test has gotten a wrong answer.
Can you help me make this more accurate? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you calculating the same numerator for `h1, h2` and `h3`?  Calculate the numerator once and store in a constant variable.

Comment: You may want to check your input numbers before calculation.  A favorite test for online problems is using out of range data.

Comment: You could improve this question by providing examples of inputs where your program fails to provide the right output. See the help page on creating an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You question needs more clarity. Do you mean - Given a triangle with three sides, can you create another triangle with sides being the heights of the original triangle?

Anyways, for a triangle to be possible given its three sides, the sum of any two sides should be greater than the third. Being equal you will have two lines of equal length at most.

Comment: You should add, not multiply – `h1 * h2 > h3` —> `h1 + h2 > h3`, et cetera. You get the wrong answer when multiplication gives a smaller number than addition.